# Can I use the word bipartisan in a non-political context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Example:

"This wasn't a unilateral decision, but rather a bipartisan one."

Comment: *Bipartisan* means "involving support or participation by two political parties"; it is not used of other sorts of party, such as "parties" to an agreement. The adjective for a decision involving both parties to an agreement rather than just one would be *bilateral*.

Comment: "Cross-functional" might apply. *Many departments were involved in the fix, it was a real cross-functional effort*

Answer (score 1):

Many are fond of the notion that everything human is in a political context. Such chauvinistic generalities aside, 'bipartisan', strictly speaking, refers to *two parties*, whether the parties are political or not:

> **biˌpartiˈsan**, *adj.*
>   Of, representing, or composed of members of, two (political or other) parties.

["biˌpartiˈsan, adj.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19270?redirectedFrom=bipartisan (accessed May 06, 2016).]

> **bi·par·ti·san** *adj.*
>   Of, consisting of, or supported by members of two parties, especially two major political parties: a bipartisan resolution.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "bipartisan." Retrieved May 6 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bipartisan )

Note that, in the *American Heritage* definition, "especially" does not mean "invariably".

Examples of uses in contemporary literature where the parties involved are not (conspicuously) political are thin on the ground. One where the intended meaning is debatable without more extensive context is

> Amazingly, the House's DOER Act passed by a large margin (232 to 187) on June 29, as a bipartisan coalition of labor and business overcame the obstructionist efforts of the radical environmental lobby.

(From ["Lifeblood from the ocean floor: the lame-duck Congress has the opportunity to tackle U.S. dependence on foreign oil and save hundreds of billions of dollars and millions of jobs with a deep-ocean drilling bill", by William Jasper, *The New American*, Dec. 11, 2006.](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Lifeblood+from+the+ocean+floor%3A+the+lame-duck+Congress+has+the+...-a0156135303))

In the quote, it seems at first glance that the "bipartisan coalition" could refer to political parties or lobbyist parties. The former interpretation is bolstered later in the piece by this:

> They are not, and today a bipartisan majority in the House voted for both.

(op. cit.)

For your particular example, out of context,

> This wasn't a unilateral decision, but rather a bipartisan one.

other terms than 'bipartisan' might at first glance seem more appropriate. However, given context, parties other than political parties might be involved:

> The Mongols and the Goths agreed to avoid poisoning the water hole during their battle. *This wasn't a unilateral decision, but rather a bipartisan one.*

Other examples of the use of 'bipartisan' with reference to other than political parties exist in contemporary literature. Such examples are far outweighed by examples wherein the word refers to political parties but, nonetheless, the word does not refer exclusively to political parties. Rather, it refers to parties or factions of any sort, political, economic, cultural or etc.

---

In coming days, uses of 'bipartisan' with reference to alliances of conservative factions within the US Republican party are likely to become more common. While these will be uses within a defined political context, the sense of 'bipartisan' in that context will not be the sense overwhelmingly exampled in contemporary literature. The sense exampled by most contemporary use refers more precisely to an alliance of two (or more) *major* political parties.